# How to troubleshoot websites on the ipad?

Tags: html, css, ipad

so I have a site that's not nearly done yet ([eklinik](http://www.eklinik.com/website/)), and its breaking on the iPad (iOS in general actually)... Things like the footer doesn't stay fixed, there's extra padding to the right, a div that's supposed to be a 100% width/height isn't, and so on so forth...

Now, I'm not asking someone else to clean up my mess (despite how nice of a thing that would be), but I am asking how can I start troubleshooting the website on the iPad...? For desktop browsers, I can always bring up the dev tools and see what's breaking where...

I do not own a mac based system, I do have an iPad though... The Dev console in the iPad is only looking for JS errors (mostly) and doesn't show anything...

Any suggestions will help... Thanks...

PS. The site is only going to run on the latest browsers:

- Chrome 12+
- Firefox 4+
- Opera - 11+
- IE 9+ (barely)
- Safari 5+

If you do feel generous, and do want to point out mistakes (optional) I might have made, along with possible solutions (optionally optional), then feel free to drop me a line - abhishek@live.com.my... :-)

Comment: It works fine in safari non the desktop... Everything behaves... Hence the iPad specific issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question's old, but a good solution for this has come up:

[Adobe Shadow](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/shadow/)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I can edit the page on my pc and get live feedback on the iPad.

Comment: Now called Adobe Edge Inspect. Excellent solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I've had quite a few clients recently that wanted their sites to be "mobile compatible" and the best solution for checking code/css on iPad is Firebug Lite:
http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

I believe you can upload and include the javascript in your site and then automatically turn it on using a simple attribute in the html tag ( see their docs for more info).

You can also install the bookmarklet in your iPad bookmarks using this method here:
http://osxdaily.com/2011/12/02/run-firebug-on-ipad-or-iphone/

I use it using the bookmarklet method and it works. Unfortunately it is a little hard to navigate, because it doesn't handle the touch controls very well (it has trouble distinguishing between a 'hover' and a 'click), but it's better than nothing.

Regarding your actual problem, it sounds similar to an issue I recently had on one of my sites. Did you set your viewport tag? if your site is normally 960px wide, and you have a div that is using width:100%, it will look wrong on the iPad because the window on the iPad is technically only like 600px wide. So the browser thinks width:100% is 600px instead of 960px or larger. If you set the viewport to 960px, then iPad Safari says, "oh, my browser window should be 960px (instead of 600px)," and resizes accordingly.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Update: For mac lovers, you can use Coda (mac app) and Diet Coda (iPad app) and it will give you a live preview of your site on the iPad as you work in Coda on your desktop/laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I use [weinre](http://muellerware.org/papers/weinre/manual.html) to test on mobile devices, not just iPads, and it works wonders.

Answer (score -2):

If you carefully test in your PC with chrome and safari as well until you get consistent results I would expect iPad or Android tablet to render "nearly" the same...

About javascript errors you should of course avoid and fix them, are you using jQuery or any other intrinsically cross browser js framework? if not, you should! :)

Comment: there're no JS errors from what the dev tools in the browsers are telling me, and everything works nice and dandy... On the desktop... When I switch over the the iPad however, something breaks... It's almost as if the useragent styling is different in Mobile safari than it is on the desktop version...

Comment: this could be, I have been reading something telling that iPad browser is like IE6, simply not standard. We will start soon a new big web project and I plan to test everything from the beginning on iPad and Android tablets as well.

Comment: See, I've been testing the site on the iPad too... But when something breaks, there's no easy way to identify what it is... There's no debug environment (that I'm aware of) which easily tells you, "Oh, looky... Line 312 has an error"...